# getting "invalid environment marker" when trying to install my python project

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to set up a beta environment on Heroku for my Django-based project, but when I install I am getting:

> error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker:
>   python_version < '3'

I've done some googling, and it is suggested that I upgrade setuptools, but I can't figure out how to do that.  (Putting setuptools in requirements.txt gives me a different error message.)

Sadly, I'm still on Python 2.7, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the Heroku "buildpack" that I was using.  I had been using the one from "thenovices" for a long time so that I could use numpy, scipy, etc.

Sadly, that buildpack specifies an old version of setuptools and python, and those versions were not understanding some of the new instructions (python_version) in the newer setup files for cryptography.

If you're facing this problem, Heroku's advice is to move to Docker-based Heroku, rather than "traditional" Heroku.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you need Python 3.x

```
"Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'"
```

means your python version isn't older 3

Comment: I can do "pip install cryptography" on a local Python 2.7 installation, so I don't think this is a 2 vs 3 issue.  I think it has something to do with setuptools not understanding something related to "python_version".